# Parsing comments with clang AST

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, libtooling, clang-ast-matchers

I would like to parse customized tag with clang AST. Here is a simple illustration of my compilation unit input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  // \my-tags tag_A, tag_B
  printf("helloworld");
  return 0;
}
```

How can I get those tags after `\my-tags`?

After reading [clang user manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#comment-parsing-options), I realize that `-Wdocumentation`, `-fparse-all-comments` or even `-fcomment-block-commands` may meet my requirement. However, when I add one of these flags in my `compile_commands.json`, the `ASTContext.Comments.empty()` still outputs `True`. I attach my `compile_commands.json` and my clang AST frontend code below for reference.

```
// compile_commands.json
[
  {
    "directory": "/home/my/project/target/directory",
    "arguments": ["/usr/local/bin/clang", "-c", "-std=c++14", "-Qunused-arguments", "-m64", "-fparse-all-comments", "-I/usr/include", "-I/usr/local/lib/clang/10.0.0/include", "-o", "build/.objs/input/linux/x86_64/release/target/target.cpp.o", "target/target.cpp"],
    "file": "target/target.cpp"
  }
]
```

```
// CommentParser.cpp
class MyPrinter : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
  public:
    virtual void run(const MatchFinder::MatchResult &Result) {
      ASTContext *Context = Result.Context;
      SourceManager& sm = Context->getSourceManager();
      if (!Context->Comments.empty())
        llvm::outs() << "There is no parsed comment\n";
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  // CommonOptionsParser OptionsParser(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
  std::string err;
  std::unique_ptr<CompilationDatabase> cd = CompilationDatabase::autoDetectFromSource("/home/my/project/target/directory/compile_commands.json", err);

  ClangTool Tool(*cd, cd->getAllFiles());

  MyPrinter Printer;
  MatchFinder Finder;

  StatementMatcher functionMatcher =
    callExpr(callee(functionDecl(hasName("pthread_mutex_lock")))).bind("functions");

  Finder.addMatcher(functionMatcher, &Printer);

  return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&Finder).get());
}
```

Comment: I can't see the comments even if I utilize `clang-check -ast-dump input.c --extra-arg=-fparse-all-comments`

Answer (score 2):

`-fparse-all-comments` works for me.

Maybe you can try not to use LibASTMatcher.

code example:

```cpp
virtual void HandleTranslationUnit(clang::ASTContext& context) {
    auto comments = context.Comments.getCommentsInFile(
        context.getSourceManager().getMainFileID());
    llvm::outs() << context.Comments.empty() << "\n";
    ...
    for (auto it = comments->begin(); it != comments->end(); it++) {
      clang::RawComment* comment = it->second;
      std::string source = comment->getFormattedText(context.getSourceManager(),
          context.getDiagnostics());
      llvm::outs() << source << "\n";
    }
}
```

reference: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html